# Total Variation in multidimension

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation, total-variation

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has bounded variation if
\begin{eqnarray}
TV_{\mathbb{R}^2}(f):=\sup\limits_{\phi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^2), ||\phi||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)}\leq 1}\, \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x,y)\operatorname{div} \phi(x,y)\, dy dx < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}

I am trying to prove the following characterization of the above definition of total variation of a function of two variable in terms of the total variation of the one variable function.
\begin{eqnarray}
TV_{\mathbb{R}^2}(f) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}TV_{\mathbb{R}}(f(\cdot,y))\, dy+ \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}TV_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x,\cdot))\, dx.
\end{eqnarray}

P.S: I could prove that
\begin{eqnarray}
TV_{\mathbb{R}^2}(f)\leq \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}TV_{\mathbb{R}}(f(\cdot,y))\, dy+ \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}TV_{\mathbb{R}}(f(x,\cdot))\, dx.
\end{eqnarray}

How to prove the other way round?

Comment: Can you prove the one dimensional version, that is, can you show $ TV_{\mathbb{R}}(f)$ is equivalent to $\sup\limits_{\phi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}), ||\phi||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}\leq 1}\, \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) \phi'(x)\, dx$?

Comment: This was exactly the very first definition of functions of bounded variation (in the sense of Tonelli and Cesari): a function such that its $1$-dim variation along every line parallel to a given axis is finite almost everywhere. Perhaps the [answer of Piotr Hajlasz to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296350/is-the-intersection-of-two-caccioppoli-i-e-finite-perimeter-sets-caccioppoli) could give you some insight.

Comment: Once you have the 1D version, you get the 2D version by noting that $\text{div}\phi = \frac\partial{\partial x} \phi_1(x,y) + \frac\partial{\partial y} \phi_2(x,y)$, and also noting that $\|\phi\|_\infty$ is equivalent to $\max\{\|\phi_1\}_\infty, \|\phi_2\}_\infty\}$.