# Properties of functions of bounded variation in multi-dimension

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, bounded-variation, total-variation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function of bounded variation.
Then do we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}}|f(x)-f(y)|\phi_{\epsilon}(|x-y|)dx dy \leq \epsilon TV(f)
\end{eqnarray}
Where $\phi_{\epsilon}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Friedrichs mollifier.

If so how to prove it?

P.S.: Definition of total variation in multi dimension can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803141/total-variation-in-multidimension)